# using python to replace an existing child attribute value with a child tag value

Tags: python, xml, replace, match, elementtree

I want to be able to parse through multiple `ReportCharacters` and make sure that all are using the `characterID` number in the `ReportCharacter` name attribute and not the actual characters name.

How can I parse, and compare the `ReportCharacter name` and if the `CharacterID` is not there, replace the name with the corresponding `CharacterID` value?

This is some sample original file:

```
'    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <CharacterData>
    <Report>
    <ReportCharacter name="scoobydoo">
    <CharacterProperties>
    <tag name="charactername">scoobydoo</tag>
    <tag name="characterID">1024724312</tag>
    <tag name="characterSTART">Sat Sep 15 02:01:56 2018</tag>
    </CharacterProperties>
    </ReportCharacter>
    <ReportCharacter name="mickey">
    <CharacterProperties>
    <tag name="charactername">mickey</tag>
    <tag name="characterID">1024724313</tag>
    <tag name="characterSTART">Sat Sep 15 02:01:56 2018</tag>
    </CharacterProperties>
    </ReportCharacter>
    <ReportCharacter name="goofy">
    <CharacterProperties>
    <tag name="charactername">goofy</tag>
    <tag name="characterID">1024724314</tag>
    <tag name="characterSTART">Sat Sep 15 02:01:56 2018</tag>
    </CharacterProperties>
    </ReportCharacter>
    </Report>
    </CharacterData>'
```

This is what I would like the modified file to look like:

```
'    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <CharacterData>
    <Report>
    <ReportCharacter name="1024724312">
    <CharacterProperties>
    <tag name="charactername">scoobydoo</tag>
    <tag name="characterID">1024724312</tag>
    <tag name="characterSTART">Sat Sep 15 02:01:56 2018</tag>
    </CharacterProperties>
    </ReportCharacter>
    <ReportCharacter name="1024724313">
    <CharacterProperties>
    <tag name="charactername">mickey</tag>
    <tag name="characterID">1024724313</tag>
    <tag name="characterSTART">Sat Sep 15 02:01:56 2018</tag>
    </CharacterProperties>
    </ReportCharacter>
    <ReportCharacter name="1024724314">
    <CharacterProperties>
    <tag name="charactername">goofy</tag>
    <tag name="characterID">1024724314</tag>
    <tag name="characterSTART">Sat Sep 15 02:01:56 2018</tag>
    </CharacterProperties>
    </ReportCharacter>
    </Report>
    </CharacterData>'
```

Comment: I did try some python and am able to parse, but am new to python and am stuck.                                     import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('characters.txt')
root = tree.getroot()

    
root.tag
root.attrib
#for child in root:
#    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
    
for ReportCharacter in root.iter('ReportCharacter'):
    if ReportCharacter.attrib == root.iter('CharacterID'):
        print(ReportCharacter.attrib,"nothing wrong")     <- this didnt give me any results...i have tried other ways as well. I was trying to see if I could even match the two

Comment: Please post your code in the question, properly formatted, it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('characters.txt')
root = tree.getroot()

for character in root.iter('ReportCharacter'):
    current_name = character.get('name', '')
    if current_name.isdecimal():
        continue

    name = character.findtext('.//tag[@name="characterID"]')
    if name:
        character.set('name', name)

with open('characters_parsed.xml', 'w') as file_out:
    tree.write(file_out, encoding='unicode', short_empty_elements=True)
```

Comment: This works until it comes to a node that doesnt have a characterID. Apparently there are a couple like that but they have the correct ReportCharacter value. How would I skip over those. Right now it runs and stops at the first one with this type of setup.

Comment: here is the error:   File "/home/test01/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1058, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)

TypeError: cannot serialize None (type NoneType)       I was thinking of using an if (character ==0): print() # but it didnt work...I dont want to add anything to the reportcharacter if it is already correct and/or doest have a characterID.   Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: i didnt reallize these type of records existed, sorry for adding to the mix.

Comment: Also to clarify the comment "add anything to the reportcharacter if it is already correct"  It is correct if it is already a numeric value and not a character name.

Comment: I am continuing reviewing the output that did work (it worked up to the point of the error mentioned above). Since I am also learning xml at the same time one note that i have after reviewing the output is that ET optimizes what it writes back to the file. Am I assuming correctly here... an example of what I am seeing here is, from a diff of the input to the output:  < <preferenceValues></preferenceValues>
< <selectedValue></selectedValue>
---
> <preferenceValues />
> <selectedValue />
5435,5436c5434,5435

Comment: it appears to have consolidated the tags down to just one set of brackets if no value existed. is that normal for xml or could that have consequences?

Comment: Yes that is valid XML, is called short empty elements, and it can be controlled in the `tree.write()` call, I will edit the code to account for the missing IDs and valid ReportCharacter names

Comment: The final edit ran without issue. Perfect and simple. I love it. you rock, Dalvenjia!